# knowing if a Kusto table has overridden cahcing/retention policy

Tags: azure-data-explorer

When we fire the following command against a specific database , we get all the policy info for all the tables in that database:-

`.show tables details`

But how to determine if a certain policy (e.g. Caching or Retention) that is shown there is because it is inherited from database policy or it is specifically overridden for that table (which is supported too) ? Is there a command to get that information as well , some sort of per table per policy level flag which will tell us if it was overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- to see a policy defined at database level (or `null`, if not defined at database-level), run: `.show database DATABASE_NAME policy POLICY_KIND`.

  - for example: `.show database MyDatabase policy retention`
- to see a policy defined at table level (or `null`, if not defined at table-level), run: `.show table TABLE_NAME policy POLICY_KIND`.

  - for example: `.show table MyTable policy retention`.
  - if this returns `null` as the `Policy` - the database-level policy, if set, is in effect.

as you mentioned correctly, `.show tables details` shows you the effective policy on the table, taking into account both database-level and table-level policies, if those are set (not `null`).

Comment: so when I look at the result of show table MyTable policy retention , it is also effective retention policy right -- what if I want to see only those tables which have overridden database retention policy for example , there is nothing that can tell me that , apart from obviously comparing database retention period with what this command returns?

Comment: `.show table T policy P` shows you the policy that was set at table level, or `null`, if it wasn't set. in case of the latter, the database-level policy, if one was set, is the effective policy